# What does calling super() in a React constructor do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, ecmascript-6

Learning React from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html) and came across this example:

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: null,
    };
  }
  ...
}
```

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), super allows you to use `this` in the constructor. Is there any other reason to use a standalone `super` (I know `super` allows you to access parent class's methods as well) but with React is there any other use case of just calling `super()` by itself?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`super()` is called inside a react component only if it has a constructor. For example, the below code doesn't require super:

```
class App extends React.component {
    render(){
        return <div>Hello { this.props.world }</div>;
    }
}
```

However if we have a constructor then `super()` is mandatory:

```
class App extends React.component {
    constructor(){
        console.log(this) //Error: 'this' is not allowed before super()

    }
}
```

The reason why `this` cannot be allowed before `super()` is because `this` is uninitialized if `super()` is not called. However even if we are not using `this` we need a `super()` inside a constructor  because `ES6 class constructors MUST call super if they are subclasses`. Thus, you have to call `super()` as long as you have a constructor. (But a subclass does not have to have a constructor.)

We call `super(props)` inside the constructor if we have to use `this.props`, for example:

```
class App extends React.component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props); // prints out whatever is inside props

    }
}
```

I hope I could make it clear.

Comment: so is the main purpose of having a constructor inside a component is to take some action immediately after the initialization of the component? super will then allow you 1.) access to `this` and 2.) if it takes props as a parameter, access to its parents props?

Comment: does super allow you to access the parent component's props?

Comment: You won't be able to access parent components props with super

Comment: Why doesn't it just call super() by default if it's a subclass? Makes no sense. Unnecessary line.

Answer (score 152):

`super()` will call the `constructor` of its `parent` class. This is required when you need to access some variables from the parent class.

In React, when you call `super` with props, React will make `props` available across the component through `this.props`. See example 2 below

**without `super()`**

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 'hello'
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(){
    console.log(this.a) //throws an error
  }
}

console.log(new B())
```

**with `super()`**

```js
class A {
  constructor(props) {
    this.props = props
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(this.props)
  }
}

console.log(new B({title: 'hello world'}))
```

Comment: +1 much more clear explanation than the accepted answer. You could make your answer shorter and more to the point too.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so it is a different behavior than the prototype chain that will dive down to fetch a prototype function in some way

Comment: Why did you remove the string in A in the super example? https://jsfiddle.net/vbuoc378/1/

Comment: I have an intuition as if this is not necessary. But it is, if not it is just making a huge assumption (passing props implicitly into the parent class, effectively assuming that it will be the same). Thanks for this answer very clarifying. +1

Answer (score 4):

Worth adding that `super()` is short for superclass contructor, a concept from [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)).

By default the class `Square` inherits the constructor from its superclass `React.Component`.

The inherited constructor can be overridden by declaring a new `constructor()` method.

If the intention is to extend rather than override the superclass constructor then it must be explicitly invoked using `super()`.

Answer (score 2):

When implementing the constructor for a `React.Component subclass`, you should call `super(props)` before any other statement. Otherwise, `this.props` will be `undefined` in the constructor, which can lead to bugs.

Comment: [Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, super refers to the parent class constructor.

Importantly, you can’t use this in a constructor until after you’ve called the parent constructor. JavaScript won’t let you:
But we forgot that if a function is called before the super() call had a chance to set up this.name. So this.name isn’t even defined yet! As you can see, code like this can be very difficult to think about.
To avoid such pitfalls, JavaScript enforces that if you want to use this in a constructor, you have to call super first. Let the parent do its thing! And this limitation applies to React components defined as classes too:

Answer (score 0):

super(); is not required by react, but is mandated by ES6 subclass

Answer (score -1):

To use `this` keyword we should use the `super` keyword before it. Why? `super` is used to call the parent class's `constructor`.

Now why do we need to call the parent's `constructor`? The answer is to initialize the properties values which we are referring through `this` keyword.