# Why does react class component always need to call super(props) in its constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In [the tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) published by reactjs.org, it was stated that "Class components should always call the base constructor with `props`". In my own research, it seems that `super(props)` can be replaced by `super()` if `this.props` is not used in the constructors, according to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e).

Therefore, my question is, why should we always pass in `props` to base constructor in reactjs? Is the advice sound? Why is the advice sound (or not sound)?

P.S. A screenshot is uploaded to this question just in case the original tutorial is updated while this question is being answered.

[image: reactjs tutorial]

Comment: React aside, you should always be calling the parent constructor with the arguments it expects. You cannot assume that not calling the parent constructor will be fine.

Comment: Well, I think my question is on the `props` part, not the `super()` part. However, I am very surprised to get a lot of knowledge from answers concerning the `super()` part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Although it is suggested to pass props to `super` but it isn't
>   strictly necessary.

Passing it just helps in an odd situation where you might have a called a method in constructor and then at some point of time in future decided to use props in it. Now since props aren't available in the constructor since you haven't passed props to `super`, it would result in an error. This kind of situation might be tricky to debug and hence its recommended to pass props always whenever you write a constructor so that it ensures `this.props` is set even before the constructor exits.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning [what the `super` constructor actually does](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/ba6477aa3cc0b189f4c9b805bf20edb2a2d94e91/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L21-L29) - namely it sets `this.props`, `this.context`, and some internal data structures.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, super refers to the parent class constructor.

**Why do we call super? Can we not call it? If we have to call it, what happens if we don’t pass props? Are there any other arguments?**

Read the article that is linked below to get the answers for the above questions.

[Read the article from Dan Abramov (Works at React JS team)](https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are initializing the parent component `React.Component` e.g. `this.props` will be undefined. You can find detailed explanation for why we are using it in [blog](https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/) by Dan Abramov, react engineer

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, its used to call your parent class constructor which is very much required, when calling **super()**, it actually calls the parent class constructor and also in
**ES** class constructor must have `super()` when its a subclass and`super()` is required only when you have a constructor explicitly.

> **Super()** not required

```
class TestApp extends React.component{
   render(){
      return <div>I don't need a super()</div>
   }
}
```

> **Super()** required

```
class TestApp extends React.component{
   constructor(){
     super(); // here super is required becuase it calls the parent class constructor //
   }

   render(){
      return <div>I don't need a super()</div>
   }
}
```

Using `super()` you can also pass props `super(props)` to the parent class, in this case, `props` will be accessible across components via `this.props`.

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary [Is super necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433463/what-does-calling-super-in-a-react-constructor-do)

since class Clock extends React.Component, you can access all the properties and methods of React.Component.

By calling super, you are actually calling the parent element with props parameter

If you intend on using this.props inside the constructor, you have to call super(props)