# React Constructor: "super" keyword is coming with a Strike through

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-class-based-component

I'm making a new react app and this happened with me for the first time.
I am using class-based components for now.
I was initializing a variable in `this.state` inside the **constructor** and caught up with this weird issue.

**Issue** :Strike Through on **super** keyword.   
 like this : <strike>**super**</strike> 
Please Check the Screenshot Below.

Note: No errors in the console or terminal

What could be the reason behind it & what is the solution ? 
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does calling super() in a React constructor do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433463/what-does-calling-super-in-a-react-constructor-do)

Comment: Not really, I have checked this question already. I want to know why is this happening. Its not happening with another project of mine which made a few weeks back.

Comment: I think this is a bug/issue w/ either Typescript or DefinitelyTyped: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40511

Comment: The link has many answers. One says "super is not needed in react classes". What if you hover the keyword in vscode?

Comment: (the strikethrough in VSCode indicates that the behavior is documented as being deprecated)

Comment: Just saw that. It says deprecated. https://prnt.sc/uijufk. But how to resolve it now ?