# Why I should use Constructor and Super functions for using Props?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I use `this.props` without any `constructor` and `super`, it works well.
So my question is why someone use this code :

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps the person who wrote the code wasn't aware that writing it out manually when that's all the constructor contains is unnecessary.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433463/what-does-calling-super-in-a-react-constructor-do

Comment: @CertainPerformance Maybe

Answer (score 0):

You can completely skip the constructor if you don't have anything to initialize.
But if you need to initialize something ( for example, state )then you need to use the constructor

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      comments:[],
      selectedComment : null
    };
```

In the above code, we are using the constructor to initialize the state variables comment and selectedComment. Since you are extending your class from React.Component, you always have to call super in your constructor otherwise you will get an error.

By using an alternative class syntax, you can leave out the constructor and initialize the state as class field declaration

```
state = {
  comments:[],
  selectedComment : null
};
```

If you follow the above approach, there is no need to use the constructor function.

Comment: I use React.Component without constructor and have no problem.